# Cannot resolve method 'OnListItemClick'

Tags: java, android, listview, pdf, android-fragments

I get this error - Cannot resolve method 'onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,android.view.View,int,long)'
I have tried using the onClickListener method but that does not work.
Please suggest.

Here is the code-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
ListView listview;


String[] pdflist;
File[] imagelist;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);


    File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
        }
    });
    pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
        pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
    }
    listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));

        }


protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String path = imagelist[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();
    openPdfIntent(path);
}



private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
    try {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
        intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: try extending class to `ListActivity`

Comment: I cannot since I need to include action bar features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
 yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Worked for me.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line from

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener, OnItemClickListener {
```

and add following line in `onCreate()` method:

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```